# Even-order derivative of $y = x\sin (x)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, induction

How do I find the general formula for the even-order derivative of $y = x\sin (x)$?

I tried using integration by parts and separation followed by mathematical induction, but I failed to obtain the correct answer, which is:

$$\frac {\mathsf d^{2n}y}{\mathsf dx^{2n}} = (−1)^n(x\sin (x) − (2n\cos (x))).$$

Comment: Can you show what did you try? If you differentiate $\frac {d^{2n}y}{dx^{2n}}$ = $(−1)^n⋅(x⋅sin (x) − (2n⋅cos (x)))$ twice, you should get what you want easily (if you rules for differentiation are used correctly)

Comment: Take the derivative twice, and then two more times and note the similarities between the second and forth derivative.  It should be fairly clear at that stage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the induction proof we need to prove that $(n=1)$

$$\frac {d^{2}y}{dx^{2}} =  2⋅\cos (x) - x⋅\sin (x)$$

and $(n \to n+1)$

$$\frac {d^{2(n+1)}y}{dx^{2(n+1)}} = (−1)^{n+1}⋅(x\sin (x) − (2(n+1)\cos (x)))$$

The first equation is easy to derive. For the second equation we basically have to take

$$\frac {d^{2}}{dx^{2}} \left( \frac {d^{2n}y}{dx^{2n}}\right) = \frac {d^{2}}{dx^{2}} \left( (−1)^{n}⋅(x\sin (x) − 2n\cos (x)) \right)$$

since we assume that the equation is valid up to the number $n$ (induction hypothesis). We get

$$\frac{d}{dx} \left( (−1)^{n} ⋅ (\sin(x) + x \cos(x) + 2n\sin(x) \right)$$

which leads to

$$\frac {d^{2}}{dx^{2}} \left( \frac {d^{2n}y}{dx^{2n}}\right) = (−1)^{n} ⋅ (\cos(x) + \cos(x) - x \sin(x) + 2n\cos(x) \\ =  (−1)^{n} ⋅ (- x \sin(x) + 2(n+1)\cos(x)) = (−1)^{n+1} ⋅ (x \sin(x) - 2(n+1)\cos(x)) =\frac {d^{2(n+1)}y}{dx^{2(n+1)}}$$

which completes the induction proof.